# How to append values to an Array in Structured text in PLC software like twincat

Tags: plc, twincat, structured-text

I have to sorting algorithm to sort out recipes from one of my machines. Is there a way to push/append values into my array?

Comment: Can you clarify a few thing: What you mean with regard to push/append?
Is this an array of unknown size that you are adding elements onto? 
Are you removing elements from the array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard List or similar implementation in the Beckhoff/TwinCAT libraries.

Best choice would be to make your own.
Make a function block containing an array and public method for appending (and other functionality you want).
Internally in the function block you then keep track of which indices are used and which are free.